# Запись в файл меняет все данные в нём на вписываемые данные

Tags: python, файлы

Есть часть кода, которая вписывает в файл id из вк, когда боту пишет человек, но когда запись в файл происходит старый id вместе с добавление нового меняется на новый.
Вот код:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.object.from_id and event.object.text=="Привет":
        k=str(event.object.from_id)
        f = open('C:/idvk.txt','a')
        try:
            f.write(k)
            f.write('\n')
        finally:
            f.close()
```

Comment: Где в коде добавление?

Comment: Попробуй `f.write(k)` присвоить к переменной,по логике у тебя должно быть все верно,хз почему не работает

Comment: @krytoy4el Как присвоение имени результату может помочь?)

Comment: У Вас всё записывается в одну строку, может Вы просто не заметили добавление нового `id`?

Comment: Простите не заметил, в коде есть строчка f.write('\n')